# Making a django form interactive

Tags: javascript, html, django

html file

```
  <div id="calculator">
    <h2>Kalkuleeri saematerjali hind</h2>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'products' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <label>Valige materjali kvaliteet/tüüp:</label><br>
      <select name="tyyp">
        <option value="taiskant">Täiskant</option>
        <option value="v_poomkant">Väike Poomkant</option>
        <option value="s_poomkant">Suur Poomkant</option>
        <option value="voodrilaud">Voodrilaud</option>
      </select><br><br>
      {% if not tyyp %}
      <button type="submit">Edasi</button><br><br>
      {% endif %}
    </form>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'products' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% if tyyp %}
      <label>Valige mõõdud: (Paksus mm x Laius mm)</label><br>
      <select name="moot">
        {% for product in products %}
        <option value="1">{{ product.nimi }}</option>
        {% endfor %} 
      </select><br><br>
      <label>Pikkus:</label><br>
      <select name="pikkus">
        <option value="kunikolm">Kuni 3,1 m</option>
        <option value="kolmkuniviis">3,2 - 5,1 m</option>
        <option value="viiskunikuus">5,2 - 6,0 m</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <label>Kogus:</label><br>
      <input type="number" required>
      <select name="yhik">
        <option value="tm">Tihumeetrit</option>
        <option value="jm">Meetrit</option>
        <option value="lauda">Lauda</option>
      </select><br><br>
      <button type="submit">Kalkuleeri</button>
      <input type="text" class="calculator-screen" value="" disabled />
      {% endif %}
    </form>
```

views.py file

```
def products_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    taiskant_list = Taiskant.objects.all()
    s_poomkant_list = S_Poomkant.objects.all()
    v_poomkant_list = V_Poomkant.objects.all()
    voodrilaud_list = Voodrilaud.objects.all()
    context = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        tyyp = request.POST['tyyp']
        context['tyyp'] = tyyp
        
        if request.POST['tyyp']=="taiskant":
            context['products'] = taiskant_list

            return render(request, "products.html", context)

        elif request.POST['tyyp']=="s_poomkant":
            context['products'] = s_poomkant_list
            return render(request, "products.html", context)

        elif request.POST['tyyp']=="v_poomkant":
            context['products'] = v_poomkant_list
            return render(request, "products.html", context)

        elif request.POST['tyyp']=="voodrilaud":
            context['products'] = voodrilaud_list
            return render(request, "products.html", context)
        
    else:
        return render(request, "products.html", context)
```

The problem is, I am trying to create a live form(after choosing first select form option, it automatically renders second select form options without pressing a button).
It should be calculator, but without "Calculate button". It has to update/fill rest of the forms depending on first form choice. And after filling 4 fields, it calculates the "price".
Should I use Django-Forms or html/js for this?

Feel free to ask any questions if I didnt express myself understandably.

Comment: IMO, you should look into a front-end framework like angular / vue / react and just use django as a backend api / admin console. That being said, I think you want to do most of this in the html / js.

Comment: Yes that might be true, but this is our course final project and we need to use django.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for homework, I'll point you in the right direction.

Let's say we have Make and Model of cars (a common example). There are a number of ways to create a dynamic form and store the data. You could use a dict or you could store the items in the db.

You would need a function that your front-end could call:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_models(request, make):
    # query the db, or get the results from a global / readonly dict?
    data = global_model_dict[make]
  
    # return json for the js caller
    return JsonResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

Add an entry in "urls" for it.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # whatever else you have in here
    path('models/<str:make>', views.get_models)
]
```

Finally, you'd need some javascript to call it. JQuery would be simple to include and would help this a lot. Something like this:

```
var settings = {
  "url": "/myapp/models/honda",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

From there, you'll have the data you need to append / set html on the page. You'll do that with a loop where I have "console.log" right now.

Some sources for you to read.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
- https://api.jquery.com/